# I have one database (mysql). What is the best "failover" strategy?

Tags: mysql, scalability, failover

Does MySQL come with a built-in automatic failover?
Or, are there load-balancers out there that can "detect" whether the database is alive...and if not...shoot it to the failover database?

I know basic MySQL, but do not know the best way to design failover for one master DB.

Comment: I'd say this is serverfault material

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full complete MySQL database replication? Ideas? What do people do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798/full-complete-mysql-database-replication-ideas-what-do-people-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798/full-complete-mysql-db-replication-ideas-what-do-people-do) might be of help to you: