# Ninja replication!

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full complete MySQL database replication? Ideas? What do people do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798/full-complete-mysql-database-replication-ideas-what-do-people-do)

Yo,

I got some data spread out on various servers (dont ask, it just have to be that way) and i really want them all in a master - slave relation so that i can update through one server but they are all on shared VPS webhosts.

So, is there a ninja way of doing this?

Comment: Now I'm disappointed. I was hoping for a post related to genetics, cloning and martial arts...

Answer (score 6):

The real ninja way is to read [replication documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html)